# JxBrowser causes the thread to be deadlock for 120 seconds

Tags: java, jxbrowser

I am currently developing an application, where I need to initiate multiple JxBrowser. 
And in the case, when I run my application, with JxBrowser, I try to fully utilitize my CPU usage, 100% 
and memory consumption on around 85%. 
Then I start to use a Java Swing UI thread to open one screen at a time. Before the first screen finish initialized, 
I create another screen, which causes the following error.

`com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.BrowserException: Failed to load 'about:blank' web page within 120 seconds.
2017-04-13 15:05:23 257 ->[AWT-EventQueue-0]--[DEBUG]--[System]--com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.BrowserException: Failed to load 'about:blank' web page within 120 seconds.
 at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser.b(Unknown Source)
2017-04-13 15:05:23 258 ->[AWT-EventQueue-0]--[DEBUG]--[System]-- at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser.b(Unknown Source)
 at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser.<init>(Unknown Source)
2017-04-13 15:05:23 258 ->[AWT-EventQueue-0]--[DEBUG]--[System]-- at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser.<init>(Unknown Source)
2017-04-13 15:05:23 258 ->[AWT-EventQueue-0]--[DEBUG]--[System]-- at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser.<init>(Unknown Source)
...`

What causes the error so problematic is that I am using a GUI thread to create a browser, as a result, 
my GUI thread is locked for 120 second, then released. And the above error message will be shown.

Currently, I am using a computer, with os = windows 7, i5 cpu, 8gb ram. 
And JxBrowser = 6.6, and upgrading to 6.13 does not resolve the issue either. 
Also I am using lightweight, instead of heightweight BrowserType, for integration with JInternalFrame.

In the case, when I am just opening my application normally, with 3 jxBrowser opened one after the other. It works as expected. 
Does anyone have any idea on what is happening?

I have researched for some time, and see [someone saying that there is a deadlock problem when using Mac OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41557279/jxbrowser-java-ipc-external-true-vm-argument)
And I try to add the VM argument, `java.ipc.external=true`, but it doesn't help.

Does anyone have any idea, what's going on? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you create several `Browser` instances with different `BrowserContext` instances configured to use the same Chromium profile directory. Please note that Chromium doesn't allow using the same profile directory in different `BrowserContext` instances or processes at the same time. It might lead to different unexpected issues including freezing or even crash in Chromium engine.

In [JxBrowser 6.14](https://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser) we added code that validates profile directory and throw an exception when the directory is already used by another `BrowserContext` instance or process. You can try 6.14 version. It will help you to determine root cause of this issue.

Comment: How do I change the Chromium profile directory? Is there a specific setter I could use?

Comment: @SajithDilshan See the example at https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000012878-creating-browser

Comment: Thank you for the detailed link